# What is the difference between a float and a double in maya?

Tags: python, double, maya, difference, setattr

In Maya, when using the setAttr() command, we can use float and double as a variable type. What is the difference? The example in the documentation is the same one.

**-type float3**

```
Array of three floats
Value Syntax    float float float
Value Meaning   value1 value2 value3
Mel Example     setAttr node.float3Attr -type float3 1.1 2.2 3.3;
Python Example  cmds.setAttr('node.float3Attr',1.1,2.2,3.3,type='float3')
```

**-type double3**

```
Array of three doubles
Value Syntax    double double double
Value Meaning   value1 value2 value3
Mel Example     setAttr node.double3Attr -type double3 1.1 2.2 3.3;
Python Example  cmds.setAttr('node.double3Attr',1.1,2.2,3.3,type='double3')
```

http://download.autodesk.com/global/docs/maya2014/en_us/CommandsPython/index.html

Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Floating point numbers are 32 bit.
Double floating point numbers are 64 bit

Doubles can hold a larger and more precise number.

Comment: Note that this is not true of Python `float`s, which are 64 bit.

Comment: Most of the time Maya uses doubles for angle values where small errors matter more.